# Find common values in multiple lists

Tags: python, list

So I have lists of numbers, and I would like to find numbers that exist in all the lists. I prefer not to use loop if possible.

Here is one example

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
c = [3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12]
df['A'] = [a, b, c]
```

The output is expected to be

```
[3, 4]
```

My problem here is, the number of lists is not given and not fixed. It can be about 20 lists with different lengths (e.g. [a, b, c, d, e, g, ..., l])

I have seen answers using set(a) & set(b) & set(c), but I am not sure how to apply this in my case.

Comment: Do your list have always unique values? e.g. it will never be something like `[1,2,2,3]`

Comment: Right. All unique values with no duplicate

Comment: Well, what you posted brings exactly what you're looking for: `set(a) & set(b) & set(c)` , brings `{3, 4}` , if you want your result as a list, you could do `list(set(a) & set(b) & set(c))`

Comment: Well, the number of set() will vary. It could be 2, or 20, 30. each time I run the script.

Comment: So, if a, b, c is given, this function will do set(a)&set(b)&set(c), but in the following run, it could be a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i. In this case, I cannot use the function and I may need to create a second function that gets 9 inputs. I wonder if there is one function that can deal with changing number of inputs.

Comment: `lst = [a, b, c]; first, *rest = lst; set(first).intersection(*rest)`

Comment: That's a poor dupe in my opinion. It is 2/3 about parsing a string of ints and 1/3 about set intersection.

Comment: Agreed; and the question is really about doing with an arbitrary list of sets, not about between explicit sets.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use **[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)** along with [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> c = [3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12]
>>> elements_in_all = list(set.intersection(*map(set, [a, b, c])))
>>> elements_in_all
[3, 4]
```

Comment: Oh thanks! This solved my issue.

Comment: Faster alternative: `elements_in_all = set(a).intersection(b, c)`. If you have a list of list: `elements_in_all = set(lst[0]).intersection(*lst[1:])`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you'd want to avoid loops, since that's .. really what you're asking for - looping over a list of lists and keeping the set of unique values.

```
l = [a, b, c]
s = None

for e in l:
  if not s:
    s = set(e)
  else:
    s &= set(e)

s => set([3, 4])
```

You can also create a functional version that doesn't explicitly use loops, and still support an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
reduce((lambda x,y: x & y), map(set, l))
```

First, convert every list in your containing list `l` to a set, then use reduce to apply the intersection for each element contained - the result is a single set with the elements common to all lists.

Comment: The reduce function is nice! Also we can generate the set of unique elements by using ``x | y`` instead of ``x & y``,

Comment: Also it can be written succinctly as ``import operator; reduce(operator.or_, map(set, l))``

Answer (score 3):

```
In [29]: a = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
    ...: b = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
    ...: c = [3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [31]: a, b, c = map(set, (a,b,c))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [32]: a.intersection(b,c)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[32]: {3, 4}
```