# Find common values in i number of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, set-intersection

I wish to do what is described in this previous question but instead of lists `a,b,c` I have `i` number of lists (that is set based on user input):

[Find common values in multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57210753/find-common-values-in-multiple-lists)

How can I change the code from this question (shown below) to work with `i` number of lists?

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> c = [3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12]
>>> elements_in_all = list(set.intersection(*map(set, [a, b, c])))
>>> elements_in_all
[3, 4]
```

The issue I have is i don't know how many lists I have in advance! needs to be iterable somehow

Comment: does `list(set.intersection(*map(set, i_number_of_lists)))` help?

Comment: @enke it needs to be iterable somehow, because i dont know how many lists i have in advance, so i can't write the code like that

Comment: Enke's solution shows exactly how to deal with an unknown number of lists. What is it that you can't use?

Comment: If you want to find intersection with other sets, you could always do: `list(set(elements_in_all).intersection(*map(set, other_lists))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you get input from the user, try to store it in the list of lists,like

```
lists = [[1,2,3], [1,2]]
```

then, use that variable instead of [a, b, c], map internally iterates all these lists and convert them to set.

```
li = [[1,2,3], [1,2]]
print(list(set.intersection(*map(set, li))))
```